# How can I make Xcode give me the header file hint?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I want to write a C++ program with Xcode10, and it works fine. But I found that there is no header file hint for C++ STL. For example, when I type `#`, the hint `#include <header>` will appear.
But if I type a `'v'` at the between the angles, there will not be any name of STL, such as `vector` or something else. But the name of Objective-C header file will appear.
[image]